# Microchip 9808 temperature sensor - Incorrect calculation result

Tags: c, i2c, temperature, microchip

I am using a Microchip MCP9808 I2C temperature sensor (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-mcp9808-precision-i2c-temperature-sensor-guide/overview).

I'm having problems being able to calculate the temperature using the values I'm reading from the sensor.

The temperature is 13 bits wide. According to the datasheet, I need to send two read commands, the first read to return the upper byte and the second read will return the lower byte. 3 of the remaining bits are used to indicate temperature alarms, and 1 bit is used to indicate the sign of the reading (positive or negative).

I'm able to read the two bytes, by using the sample code from the datasheet as a starting point. However, the values I'm getting from it are incorrect. I'm also unable to get negative temperatures, so I think my code has something wrong with it.

I'm using a USB->I2C adaptor, and I've written a C# implementation of the datasheet sample code to calculate the temperature.

[image]

And then my code (which apart from some extra necessary castings due to the way C# handles data types) I think is identical.

```
    public static double CalculateAmbientTemperature(byte upperByte, byte lowerByte)
    {
        const byte ALERT_MASK_VALUE = 0x1F;
        const byte CLEAR_SIGN_MASK = 0x0F;

        double temperature = 0.00;

        upperByte = (byte)(upperByte & ALERT_MASK_VALUE);

        // Ambient temperature less than 0 degrees
        if((upperByte & (byte)(upperByte & 0x10)) == 0x10)
        {
            upperByte = (byte)(upperByte & CLEAR_SIGN_MASK);
            temperature = 256.0 - ((double)upperByte * 16.0 + (double)lowerByte / 16.0);
        }
        else
        {
            temperature = ((double)upperByte * 16.0 + (double)lowerByte / 16.0);
        }

        return temperature;
    }
```

So to test the code, I've been sending the bytes: `START_BIT 0x3E (the address) 0x05 (the address of the temperature register)` This tells the sensor to point the register pointer at the temperature register, so that when I send the two read commands, it reads from that register.

And when I read the data back, I'm getting `0xC1 0x24`. When I pass these values to the function, I'm getting 17.0625 degrees C. Bearing in mind, I'm holding an ice cube on the sensor. (Currently don't have a more precise way). So basically, my calculation is faulty but I don't know where to begin with fixing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

(EDIT: To check I'm able to read the chip correctly, I read the Manufacturer ID register and get back the expected 0x54)

Comment: Your `CLEAR_SIGN_MASK` looks incorrect. It should be `0x1F`

Comment: Oh, come on.   There's always a better way.  Crush some ice, make an ice/water slurry in a bowl, put your sensor in a plastic bag, immerse it in the ice/water mixture, and give it time to come to equilibrium.  You'll be very near zero.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How so? The datasheet says 0x0F?

Comment: @user9993 Sorry, missed one bit. Disregard :)

Comment: I manually calculate those values as 18.25 degrees. But then, I got the order of precedence right in my calculation.  Tip: don't work in double till right at the end. Keep it as integers.

Comment: @Majenko Can you explain how I can use the right precedence order with my code?

Comment: First build up a 16 bit integer from your two bytes. Then mask out the bits you don't want, then, and only then, should you divide it by 16. So you're working with 0xC124, then 0x0124, then 0x012.4

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the right data? Try reading the registers that are containing known values, and make sure you are getting them correctly.

Comment: 17.0625 would be the result from 0xC1 0x11 not 0xC1 0x24. Since byte in C# is unsigned, this looks okay, but the casts could be a problem in C/C++ if byte was signed.

Comment: Where did you buy that chip? Some distributor, or simply from china? I bought some pieces of MCP9808 from Mouser, and some from Aliexpress. Those from Mouser are reading temperature exactly as in example in datasheet. But every of those from Ali is giving very random temperature. So I considered those china chips faulty. Now I see it could be probably caused by different algorithm?

Comment: I got mine in the Adafruit boards, I've not yet bought them as IC only yet. Those ones from China sound like 100% fakes, it's nothing to do with algorithms. Are you 100% you can reproduce the problems every time? I'd personally never buy ICs or any other kind of component from Aliexpress, ever. Fake IC's/components is a very well known problem, going back decades. https://www.adafruit.com/product/1782

Comment: Yes, my original chips are measuring temperature with pretty good consistency (say 26C). But those chips from Ali are garbage. One gives around 10C, another around 20C, another around 28C, etc. They are way off. It seems the price was too good to be true. Now I see the answer from @freshness, it's about wrong calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this problem myself recently. The error originates from the manufacturer's datasheet. When the 'negative' flag is set the proper computation is:

```
temp -= 256;  // correct!
```

instead of

```
temp = 256 - temp;  // incorrect! But this is the example in the datasheet!
```

Here are a couple examples of control code for the MCP9808 on Github:

[lexruee/mcp9808](https://github.com/lexruee/mcp9808/blob/master/src/mcp9808.c)

[adafruit/Adafruit_MCP9808_Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MCP9808_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_MCP9808.cpp)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Also: I've submitted a documentation bug report to Microchip. We'll see how they respond.

Comment: Did they ever respond? @Freshness

Comment: No, they did not. I git a survey request about a year later and scored them pretty low, but no acknowledgement and no change in documentation.

Comment: How annoying! @Freshness

Comment: I have used the calculation from datasheet, and it gives correct values. Your modified equation gives false results.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: the datasheet is correct, but the sample implementation code in the datasheet is incorrect. So, do not simply copy & paste the C code from the datasheet.